# Alternative to summary() for a dataframe with +100 labeled columns - R

Tags: r, data-analysis, data-manipulation, summary

I have a `df` with +100 labeled columns and 500 rows approx. I'm trying to get an overview idea of the data, but it seems to be impossible given the huge number of columns and doing `summary()` results in an enormous and confusing summary.

I have been looking to some Github/Kaggle projects and they vary from 10MB to 100GB dataframes sizes, but I can find no one with an analysis to a large number of columns (just with millions of rows).

So, is there any kind of `summary()` function to get an overall idea of your data considering that your dataframe has +100 labeled columns with integers, floats, and categorical variables among them?

Comment: There's `summarise_at`, `summarise_if` and `summarise_all` which lets you specify column numbers, ranges or variable types to summarise

Comment: I like to use `table(sapply(df,class))`

Comment: What are you trying to get out of your summary? What kind of columns are there (not what classes, but what's the actual data about)?

Comment: Check out [`ggally::ggpairs()`](http://ggobi.github.io/ggally/#ggallyggpairs)

Comment: Perhaps try: `View(capture.output(ls.str(CO2)))` where `CO2` is a builtin data frame.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could try out the `dataMaid` package. It was created more or less exactly for this task: take a data frame and produce a document (in either word, pdf, or html format) that summarises each of the variables in the data frame.

Try the following to see what you get out of the package

```
library("dataMaid")
makeDataReport(trees)
```

You will produce a rather long document with the 100+ variables, but the report makes it easy to check the variables in the data frame.